# I want to replace multiple strings at a time using VIM Editor command

Tags: linux, gvim

```
104116001|PRODUCT|511|RAMP||2016-03-18|2016-03-23|060.00|1||R|012
104116001|PRODUCT|512|RAMP||2016-03-18|2016-03-23|060.00|1||R|012
104116001|PRODUCT|514|RAMP||2016-03-18|2016-03-23|060.00|1||R|012
104116001|PRODUCT|515|RAMP||2016-03-18|2016-03-23|060.00|1||R|012
```

In the above I want to replace `|511|` with `|211|` in the same way all `|512|` - `|212|` `|514|` - `|214|` 
and the main thing in here is I don't want replace `515` - `215` (I want it to be same).

And I used the command you mentioned:

```
:map <leader>fq :%s/a/b/ge <Bar> %s/c/d/ge <Bar> %s/e/f/ge<CR>
```

which didn't work in my case and any help on this is appreciable thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a regular expression which starts with 51 and its 3rd charactar can be any of 1,2 or 4. Then you want to replace the string that matches the regular expression this way: the first to characters be 21 and the 3rd should be whatever character matched the 3rd character specified by the regular expression (that is: no change).

```
%s/51\([124]\)/21\1/g
```

Here [124] means any of 1,2 or 4 and \([124]\) means "let's remember the character that matched [124]". In the replacement string, \1 means "the character that we remembered as the first remembered substring" (to be more specific: the substring that matched the piece of the regexp between the first \(\) pair).

Comment: That was awesome! and i want to do the same for 52 series like 521, 522.. and 53, 54 series as well in one command and please help on this too

Comment: You can probably get by without the `/g` at the end.  The search term shows up one time per line, at most.